# Помогите составить регулярку для awk, чтобы распарсить лог nginx

Tags: регулярные-выражения, парсер, логирование, awk

Задача состоит в том чтобы распарсить логи nginx и достать от туда список IP в порядке убывания по количеству совпадений. И количество совпадений. Такого формата:

```
2344 111.111.111.111
304  222.222.222.222
10   333.333.333.333
...
```

Если с `access.log` все просто:

```sh
awk '{print $1}' /var/log/nginx/access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

То с `error.log` надо доставать IP из `client: 111.222.222.222,`:

```
2023/02/02 06:19:02 [crit] 2410981#0: *50594932 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1420918C:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking, client: 111.222.222.222, server: 0.0.0.0:443

2023/02/02 08:03:12 [error] 2542542#0: *50705729 open() "/public_html/favicon-32x32.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 4a44:1111:222b:1111:1:0:ba6:d46b, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon-32x32.png HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com"
```

Comment: можно попробовать `grep -oP '(?<=client: )[^,]+(?=,) error.log` и дальше уже сортировка и так далее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
То с error.log надо доставать IP из ...
```

достать **ip** с **error.log** тоже довольно просто, например с помощью `awk` зная их уникальные разделители:

```
awk -F'client: |, server: ' 'NF>0{print $2}'
```

полно будет выглядеть так:

```
awk -F'client: |, server: ' 'NF>0{print $2}' /var/log/nginx/error.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, я как раз и имел ввиду разделители, но сам слабоват для такого

Answer (score 2):

Эта команда сделает то, что нужно:

```
cat error_log | sed -r -e 's/.*client: ([^,]+),.*/\1/ ; /^$/d' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Comment: Спасибо, так даже учитывает технические записи и не оставляет пустую строку, но все-таки, так как в вопросе писал про awk, считаю справедливым поставить отмеченным ответ от Zt.